# Alterar propriedades do componente em diferentes páginas

Tags: css, react, react-native, styled-components

Tenho um componente de botão:

Arquivo `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import {Container, Text} from './styles';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default function Button({children, loading, ...rest}) {
  return (
    <Container {...rest}>
      {loading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#fff" />
      ) : (
        <Text>{children}</Text>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Arquivo `styles.js`:

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import {RectButton} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export const Container = styled(RectButton)`
  background: #23dc42;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 46px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`
;

export const Text = styled.Text`
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
`;
```

E utilizo o botão em duas páginas, porém em uma das páginas gostaria de alterar a cor dele e manter a cor do componente nas outras. Tem como?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar `props` no seu componente estilizado. Para isso, basta utilizar a sintaxe de interpolação, passando uma função, que receberá como parâmetro as `props` passadas.

Um exemplo:

```js
const Text = styled.div`
  color: ${(props) => props.color || 'black'};
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
`;
```

E para usar, algo assim:

```js
<Text color="red">Em Vermelho</Text>
<Text color="blue">Em Azul</Text>
```

- Veja um [exemplo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sopt-441540-zyu0d) funcionando no CodeSandbox.
- Consulte a [documentação](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props) para saber mais sobre a passagem de `props` no styled-components.